# Responsive images in the same div

Tags: html, css, responsive-images

I have this simple script where i have 2 responsive images. If you minimize the window you will that the images will accordingly.

But i put 2 images in the same div like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="block">
        <img
          src=
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg"

        ></img>
        <img
          src=
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg"

        ></img>
      </div>

    </div>
```

i wont take the same effect, WHY?

https://jsfiddle.net/zqgy89k7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you still had a width of 100% per image. Setting the width to 50% makes them scale again. Also set the height to auto to remain proportions.

See example below:

```css
.wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: solid red;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid blue;
}

.block img {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can comment the `heigh: 200px` line code. And that would be a solution.

Another one is to add `flex-wrap: wrap` to the *flex-father* container, and this would be visualy more likely.

Here is the example:

[JS Fiddle with responsive images](https://jsfiddle.net/cvallejo_ec/weqvkza4/10/)